# Transform Stream<Item> to Stream<List<Item>>

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I try to get all files in folder by Stream.

`Directory(path).list()` returns `Stream<FileSystemEntity>`.

I want returns `Stream<List<FileSystemEntity>>`.

Example:

```
1 => 1
2 => 1,2
3 => 1,2,3
```

Comment: Why do you want this?  Why not have the listener append each item to its own list?

Comment: I have a StreamBuilder and is only last file in snapshot.data

Comment: Can't you have your `StreamBuilder`'s builder append each item to a list?  Making the `Stream` return a new list for each successive item would be O(n^2) and would be unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @jamesdlin you have an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scan` operator from `rxdart` is the best answer 
https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ScanExtension/scan.html
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan

```dart
Stream<FileSystemEntity> source$ = ...;

Stream<List<FileSystemEntity>> result$ = source$.scan(
    (acc, element, _) => [...acc, element],
    [],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper object to store the list

Try this as a starting point

```dart
class StreamToStreamList<T> {
  StreamToStreamList(this._parent);

  final Stream<T> _parent;
  final _values = <T>[];

  Stream<List<T>> toStream() async* {
    await for (final value in _parent) {
      _values.add(value);
      yield _values;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
  final result = Directory(path)
      // get subentries of the path dir
      .list()
      // getting only sub-directories (assumtion is that you are interested in those only)
      .where((dir) => dir is Directory)
      // casting them to Directory object
      .cast<Directory>()
      // processing each dir getting its sub-entries 
      .map((dir) => dir.listSync())
  ;
```

EDIT: case when you want result to have files also as single element of list in stream:

```dart
  final result = Directory(path)
      // get sub-entries of the path dir
      .list()
      // processing each entry so dir entry -> list of dir sub entries and file entry -> list containing one file as single element   
      .map((dir) {
        if(dir is Directory) {
          return dir.listSync();
        } else {
          return [dir];
        }
      })
  ;
```